# ¿Cómo partir una cadena en dos en cada celda de una hoja de Google?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Sobre una hoja de cálculo de google quiero poner los nombres en una primera columna, y lo que queda en la secunda. Aqui estan los datos, cada linea esta una linea en la primera columna.

```
51. Wall - Right Plaster painted white colour Good condition, medium level scuffs, red stain, 2 x plastic hooks + 2 x holes at the curtain rail level
54. Wall - Back Plaster painted white colour Burn mark near double power point + 3 screws, a hole and a wear mark
60. Contents 1 1 x double divan, 1 x double mattress
In use,wear marks + small tear and hole
64. Contents 4 1 x beech chest of drawers. last shelf a little damaged
```

Entonces hice:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
var searchRange = sheet.getRange(2,2, lastRow-1, lastColumn-1);


function splitText() {
  // Get array of values in the search Range
  var rangeValues = searchRange.getValues();
  // Loop through array and if condition met, add relevant
  // background color.
  for ( i = 0; i < lastColumn - 1; i++){
    for ( j = 0 ; j < lastRow - 1; j++){
      if(rangeValues[j][i].includes(".")){
        string = rangeValues[j][i].split('.');
        sheet.getRange(j,i+1) = string[0]; 
        sheet.getRange(j,i+1) = string[1]; 
      }; 
    };
  };
};
```

Pero obtengo:

> The number of columns in the range must be at least 1. (line 6, file "Code")

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que `var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();` está asignando 1 a la variable lastRow, entonces al hacer `lastColumn-1` en `var searchRange = sheet.getRange(2,2, lastRow-1, lastColumn-1);` tu código está pasando 0 como el cuarto argumento de `getRange` y el valor mínimo debe ser 1.

Quizás estas pasando por alto que métodos del "Spreadsheet Service" como `getRange` usan índices base 1 contrario  a los métodos de JavaScript que usando métodos base 0.